# Issue with React Native Redux state boolean going from true to false in the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In my parent component I send a prop to the children.

When I do console.log(this.state.fav) it consoles log "true" then "false" right away.

**Parent:**

```
<FlatList
  data={items}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <Item
    fav={item.fav}
  />
  )}
/>
```

**Children**

```
class Item extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fav: this.props.fav
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.fav)
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you rendering Item component. Can you post that code

Comment: Sorry, just updated my code @Dev

Comment: Can you post the `json` for the `items`, or try `console log` inside the `renderItem` to show what is the value of `item.fav`